# How do I obtain the outliers for each of my columns using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 571 columns corresponding to 571 different metabolites, and a column with participant ID. Using the code below I can identify the participants with outliers for each of the metabolites individually ( as mean +/- 3 * sd).

```
  out<-data
       [which(
             data$Met1 > mean(data$Met1, na.rm=T) + 3* sd(data$Met1, na.rm=T) |
             data$Met1 > mean(data$Met1, na.rm=T) + 3* sd(data$Met1, na.rm=T)
            ),
            ]
```

However, I would like to be able to automate this, so the output is a table with 572 columns, one for the ID numbers and then the corresponding outlier values, if any, for the 571 metabolites, with NAs filling the spaces for the metabolites that do not have an outlier for that ID. eg.

```
 ID     Met1     Met2    Met3...

 56     NA       0.145   NA
 72     0.09     0.07    NA
 98     NA       NA      0.0098
```

I am working on a for loop, but keep running into errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 for ( i in 1:ncol(data[, 2:572]){
  outlier1 <-data[,i] > mean(data[,i]) + 3*sd(data[, i])
  outlier2 <- data[,i] > mean(data[,i]) - 3*sd(data[,i])
  need <- outlier1 + outlier2
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good way: build a custom function, then apply it to your columns:

```
## custom function
show_outliers = function(x) {
  my_mean = mean(x)
  my_sd = sd(x)
  is_outlier = (x > my_mean + 3 * my_sd) | (x < my_mean - 3 * my_sd)
  x[!is_outlier] = NA
  return(x)
}

## intialize output
out = data
## apply function to all columns except the first
out[-1] = lapply(out[-1], show_outliers)
```

If instead you wanted to fix your for loop, I think this will work:

```
out <- data             ## work on out, don't modify data
for (i in 2:ncol(out) { ## start at 2, go to ncol(out)
  outlier1 <- out[,i] > mean(out[,i]) + 3*sd(out[, i])
  outlier2 <- out[,i] > mean(out[,i]) - 3*sd(out[,i])

  ## your outlier1 and outlier2 are logical
  ## so we can combine them with OR |
  outliers <- outlier1 | outlier2 
  
  ## modify the data
  out[!all_outliers, i] <- NA
} # delete extra )
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `boxplot.stats` to find the outlier

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>% 
      mutate(across(-1, 
         ~ replace(., . %in% boxplot.stats(.)$out, NA)))
```